# Change navigation bar position in Bootstrap3

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Boot Strap 3. Working on Responsive Layout.

I have a logo centered aligned and below that a navigation bar which has few links e.g. "About Us" "Contact Us" "FAQ", etc.

My Requirement is
Above 1024 resolution the navigation bar should appear below logo in a bar.

Below 1024 resolution it should be collapsed and viewed on right hand side of logo.

Please advise.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: or use [Bootply](http://bootply.com/103172) which already includes Bootstrap

Comment: Please review my site using below URL: http://idea66.com/mobile/index2.htm

Comment: So on mobile version the logo should be left aligned and the collapsible menu should be in same logo row right aligned. Currently is not happening. Please help!!!
Thank you

Comment: Isolate the css and html and any scripts and make JsBin, Bootply, or Fiddle

Comment: CSS and HTML are isolated. Downloaded boot strap.css But how to add scripts Bootply or Fiddle. Not sure about that :(

Comment: if you are using bootply, you don't need to add the bootstrap scripts or css. with fiddle, just use the [CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Comment: my thoughts is you can add a col-xs-4 next to your logo which will be visible-md (up to 992px) and contain a colapsed menu and have your nav bar visible-lg only. if it has to be 1024 so you can rewrite your own media condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1024px is not a breakpoint in the Bootstrap default configuration. You can customize the breakpoint of when the mobile navbar kicks in at the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ but it affects when everything breaks down to mobile. The default is 768px. So in the un-modified Bootstrap default everything (all forms, collapse, navbar-text, and so on) has to be changed along with the max-width of same, when applicable, so that is 767px. If you don't use LESS then this is a pain.

**This only works if you adjust all the CSS break the navbar at the points indicated in the paragraph above. In the Bin below, that's been done, you will need to search for 1023px and 1024px to see where those are located in your installation of Bootstrap. Make a backup. Also, when you update to 3.1.0 in a few days, you'll need to do this again unless you use LESS, which will make short work of this.**

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AsaRofuW/1/

### EDIT: http://jsbin.com/AsaRofuW/1/edit

---

**This is the HTML structure to center a logo below the navigation. It does not differ from the docs, except that it adds the image.**

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          
          <a href="yourlink.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg/800px-Coca-Cola_logo.svg.png" alt="company name">
          </a>
          
        </div><!--/.navbar-header-->
        
        <div id="nav-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#testme1" class="anchor">Anchor 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testme2" class="anchor">Anchor 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testme3" class="anchor">Anchor 3</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul><!--/.navbar-nav-->
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.navbar-->
```

---

**CSS**

This CSS uses the min-width 1024px. For default Boostrap 3.0.3 CSS this min-width is 768px. These add styles that differ from yours and the default bootstrap, you can remove, adjust or whatever.

```
/* logo container padding on right so it doesn't hit the toggle */
.navbar-brand {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 80px;
    float: left;
    width: 70%; /* adjust as needed */
}
/* logo image */
.navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 90px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
/* so that the navbar has some bottom white space */
.main-page {
    margin-top: 20px
}
.navbar-toggle {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:10px;
}
    

@media (min-width:1024px) { 
    .navbar-header {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -120px;
        /*logo position */
    }
    /* hide logo after scroll past navbar height */
    .showlogo {
        display: none
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -50px;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    /* brand for tablet and up */
    .navbar-brand {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar-brand img {
        max-height: 80px
    }
    /* centered navigation */
    .nav.navbar-nav {
        float: left;
        background: transparent!important;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav > li:not(.dropdown) > a:after {
        content: "/";
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 30px;
        margin-right: -30px;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav > li:last-child:not(.dropdown) > a:after {
        content: ""
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav > li.active > a,
    ul.nav.navbar-nav > li.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle {
        background: transparent;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav li.dropdown > ul {
        left: 15px
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav > li {
        position: relative;
        right: 50%;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav li {
        text-align: left
    }
    /* page styles */
    .main-page {
        margin-top: 150px
    }

}
```

---

*Note: Responsive utilities won't work inside your navbar because the media queries are changed. Lots more work to fix those, which you will need to figure out. Probably requires making two sets (about 400 more lines of CSS and isolating with a .navbar preceding the class).*

Comment: Please select it as the answer

Comment: I am facing one more issue. When adding more links in nav bar there is horizontal scroll in 1024 resolution only.

But in 1600 there is no scroll. Also I want to add the blue bar(width 100%) for only navigation in the resolution 1024 and above.

When I added bg color to nav bar its including logo container as well which I don't require

Please advise. How to select it as an answer?

Thank you

Comment: You can't have unlimited links, if the links are longer than the width of 1024 then you need to edit them to make them shorter or adjust the min-width from 1024 to something higher and the max-width to 1px under that.

Comment: Ok thank you. 
I am unable to add a blue color strip (100%) just behind menu links in 1024 resolution and above? How to add that? If I add bg color using css it also covers the logo which I don't want. The blue strip should be just below logo for menus. Please help!!!

Comment: Post a new question with your attempt so far on SO

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to bootstrap, I think sticking to an existing breakpoint would be wise, like you have in your example link.

Try putting the logo in your html twice, and show/hide either one with css via media queries matching that same breakpoint. See: http://bootply.com/103276.